# ImportError: dlopen() Symbol not found _PyMethod_New Expected in : flat namespace

Tags: python

I downloaded Attify Zipbee Framework from
https://github.com/attify/Attify-Zigbee-Framework
and I only just want to popup the application by "python main.py" and I'm getting error below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ME/Desktop/Attify-Zigbee-Framework-master/main.py", line 8, in 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0a5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/sip.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCMethod_New
Referenced from: /Users/ME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0a5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/sip.cpython-39-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/ME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0a5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/sip.cpython-39-darwin.so

I'm using Mac OS 10.15.4.
I have installed PyQt5.
which python > /Users/ME/.pyenv/shims/python
python --version > Python 3.9.0a5

For Attify Zigbee Framework, changed the import  PyQt4 to 5 due to python2 is EOL. 
What do I have to do to get this app working in my situation?
Please help me with my new learning.

#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
############################
## Attify Zigbee Framework #
############################

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QAction, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import SIGNAL
from UI.Base import Ui_MainWindow
from src.kbi import RavenRefresh, ZBDumpThread, ZBReplayThread, \
    ZBWireShark
from src.ztmThread import ZBStumblerThread
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import fnmatch


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:


    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s


class AZFMain(Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, dialog, parent=None):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        self.ToolIcon.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('UI/icon.png')))
        self.zbstumblerThread = None
        self.zbdumpThread = None
        self.zbreplayThread = None
        self.zbwiresharkThread = None
        self.ravenRefresh()
        self.pcapRefresh()
        self.pushButton_Refresh.clicked.connect(self.ravenRefresh)
        self.pushButton_zbstumbler.clicked.connect(self.zbstumblerRun)
        self.pushButton_Zbdump.clicked.connect(self.zdump)
        self.pushButton_Zbreplay.clicked.connect(self.zbreplay)
        self.wiresharkStart.clicked.connect(self.zbwireshark)
        self.attifyWebLink.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.AttifyStoreLink.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.killerbeeLink.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

    def pcapRefresh(self):

                # Function to add pcap files to the file slectors

        print('[*] pcapRefresh invoked ')
        self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Refreshing Pcap Files ',
                                   2000)
        path = 'pcap/'
        pattern = '*.pcap'
        result = []
        for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
            for name in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                    result.append(os.path.join(name))
        self.zbreplayFile.clear()
        self.zbreplayFile.addItems(result)

    def ravenRefresh(self):
        print('[*] Executing Raven Refresh ')
        self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Refreshing devices', 2000)
        self.ravenRefreshThread = RavenRefresh()
        self.ravenRefreshThread.start()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ravenRefreshThread,
                               QtCore.SIGNAL('ravenrefresh_update(QString)'
                               ), self.update_refresh_status)

    def update_refresh_status(self, QString):
        if len(str(QString)) > 50:
            self.labelDeviceStatus.setText('Connected')
            string = str(QString).split('\n')
            output = []
            for i in string:
                output.append(i.strip())
            QString = output[0] + '\n' + output[1]
            self.labelDeviceDetails.setText(QString)
        else:
            self.labelDeviceStatus.setText('Disconnected')
        self.ravenRefreshThread.close()

    def zbstumblerRun(self):
        if self.zbstumblerThread == None:
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Starting zbstumbler',
                    2000)
            print('[*] Starting zbstumbler')
            self.pushButton_zbstumbler.setText('Stop')
            channel = self.zbstumbler_Channel.currentText()
            if channel == 'Select Channel':
                channel = 11
            self.zbstumblerConsole.append('\n[ * ] Scanning channel : '
                    + channel + '\n')
            self.zbstumblerThread = ZBStumblerThread(int(channel))
            self.zbstumblerThread.start()
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.zbstumblerThread,
                                   QtCore.SIGNAL('stumbler_update(QString)'
                                   ), self.update_zbstumbler)
        else:
            print('[*] Stopping zbstumbler')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping zbstumbler',
                    2000)
            self.pushButton_zbstumbler.setText('Start')
            self.zbstumblerThread.close()
            self.zbstumblerThread = None

    def update_zbstumbler(self, QString):
        if str(QString) == 'Complete':
            print('[*] Stopping zbstumbler')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping zbstumbler',
                    2000)
            self.pushButton_zbstumbler.setText('Start')
            self.zbstumblerThread.close()
            self.zbstumblerThread = None
            self.zbstumblerConsole.append('\n[ * ] Scanning complete')
        else:
            self.zbstumblerConsole.append(QString)

    def zdump(self):
        channel = self.zbdumpChannel.currentText()
        file = self.zbdumpFile.text()
        count = self.zbdumpCount.text()
        if self.zbdumpThread == None:
            print('[*] Starting ZBdump')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Starting zbdump', 1500)
            self.pushButton_Zbdump.setText('Stop Capture')
            self.zbdumpThread = ZBDumpThread(channel, file, count)
            self.zbdumpThread.start()
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.zbdumpThread,
                                   QtCore.SIGNAL('zbdump_update(QString)'
                                   ), self.zbdump_complete)
        else:
            print('[*] Stopping ZBdump')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping zbdump', 1500)
            self.pushButton_Zbdump.setText('Start Capture')
            self.zbdumpThread.close()
            self.zbdumpThread = None

    def zbdump_complete(self):
        self.zbdumpThread.close()
        print('[*] Stopping ZBdump')
        self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping zbdump', 1500)
        self.pushButton_Zbdump.setText('Start Capture')
        self.zbdumpThread = None
        self.pcapRefresh()

    def zbreplay(self):
        channel = self.zbreplayChannel.currentText()
        file = self.zbreplayFile.text()
        count = self.zbreplayCount.text()
        delay = self.zbreplayDelay.text()
        if self.zbreplayThread == None:
            print('[*] Starting ZBreplay')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Starting zbreplay', 1500)
            self.pushButton_Zbreplay.setText('Stop Replay')
            self.zbreplayThread = ZBReplayThread(channel, file, count,
                    delay)
            self.zbreplayThread.start()
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.zbreplayThread,
                                   QtCore.SIGNAL('zreplay_update(QString)'
                                   ), self.replay_complete)
        else:
            print('[*] Stopping ZBreplay')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping zbreplay', 1500)
            self.pushButton_Zbreplay.setText('Start Replay')
            self.zbreplayThread.close()
            self.zbreplayThread = None

    def replay_complete(self):
        self.zbreplayThread.close()
        print('[*] Stopping ZBreplay')
        self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping zbreplay', 1500)
        self.pushButton_Zbreplay.setText('Start Replay')
        self.zbreplayThread = None

    def zbwireshark(self):
        count = None
        channel = self.wiresharkChannel.text()
        try:
            count = self.wiresharkCount.text()
        except Exception as e:
            print('[*] Zbwireshark count error : '  ) #str(e) 
        if self.zbwiresharkThread == None:
            print('[*] Starting ZBWireshark')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Starting ZBWireshark ',
                    2000)
            self.wiresharkStart.setText(' Stop Wireshark ')
            self.zbwiresharkThread = ZBWireShark(channel, count)
            self.zbwiresharkThread.start()
        else:
            print('[*] Stopping ZBWireshark')
            self.statusbar.showMessage(' AZF | Stopping ZBWireshark ',
                    2000)
            self.wiresharkStart.setText(' Launch Wireshark ')
            self.zbwiresharkThread.close()
            self.zbwiresharkThread = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('UI/icon.png'))
    prog = AZFMain(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```